# How to remove a XML node using JDOM?

Tags: java, xml, jdom

Here is my code:

```
try
{
    Document fichero = (Document) builder.build( xmlFile );
    Element rootNode = fichero.getRootElement();
    List list = rootNode.getChildren( "fichada" );
    for ( int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++ )
    {
        Element tabla = (Element) list.get(i);
        String term = tabla.getChildTextTrim("N_Terminal");
        String tarj = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Tarjeta");
        String fech = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Fecha");
        String horaEnXML = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Hora");
        String caus = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Causa");    
        //HERE I WANT TO DELETE THE NODE 
    }
} catch ( IOException io ) {
    System.out.println( io.getMessage() );
} catch ( JDOMException jdomex ) {
    System.out.println( jdomex.getMessage() ); 
}
```

I need to delete the node just after saving the values in the variables, how can I do it?

Comment: When you post your code on StackOverflow, please don't use non-English identifier names, because it makes code harder to read.

Comment: Do u want to delete any specific node or child node of some parent ? Give more info.

Comment: yes, the actual node in every time that i'm in the loo

Comment: should be easy by calling removeChild() on Element

Comment: removeChild needs a string, what can i do?

Answer (score 1):

"Deleting" the node has a couple of different meanings. You can remove the node from the in-memory JDOM model, and additionally, you can then overwrite the file on disk without the node, to save the modified document.

To remove the node from the XML document, you 'detach' it:

```
.....
String caus = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Causa");
tabla.detach();
```

After you detach the `tabla` element it will no longer be part of the in-memory document, but you can still reference tabla as a 'fragment' of XML.

If you want to save the modified document back to the file, you will need to write the XML back to the file:

```
try (FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(xmlfile)) {
    XMLOutputter xmlout = new XMLOutputter();
    xmlout.output(fichero, fos);
}
```

Additionally, you really should be using JDOM 2.x where generics will help make your code neater:

```
try
{
    Document fichero = (Document) builder.build( xmlFile );
    Element rootNode = fichero.getRootElement();
    for (Element tabla : rootNode.getChildren( "fichada" )) {
        String term = tabla.getChildTextTrim("N_Terminal");
        String tarj = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Tarjeta");
        String fech = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Fecha");
        String horaEnXML = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Hora");
        String caus = tabla.getChildTextTrim("Causa");    

        //HERE I WANT TO DELETE THE NODE 
        tabla.detach();
    }
} catch ( IOException io ) {
    System.out.println( io.getMessage() );
} catch ( JDOMException jdomex ) {
    System.out.println( jdomex.getMessage() ); 
}
```

Comment: I made that you said but the node is still in the document and i don't know why